# High performance $all query on mongodb sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Here's my situation: I have a mongodb cluster with 3 shards and a replica set with 3 nodes each. (I'm using Mongoid.) The documents in my collection have an array named filter_array, which has a multikey index:

```
field(:filter_array, type: Array, default: [])
index(filter_array: 1)
```

The array consists of numbers, e.g. [1,2,3] and so on. I want to be able to do fast queries on any combination of the array, which would be any one of the combinations below:

```
[3], [2], [2,3], [1], [1,3], [1,2], [1,2,3]
```

So I wonder how I have to set up the shard key for this. The mongodb docs say the following:

> If a query does not include the shard key, the mongos must direct the
>   query to all shards in the cluster. These scatter gather queries can
>   be inefficient. On larger clusters, scatter gather queries are
>   unfeasible for routine operations.

If I understand this right, there is no way to do this without a scatter/gather query - or am I missing something? The collection can potentially have millions of documents and the array can have 20 elements or even more.

Comment: Do you need to shard the data ? Millions of documents is not that big, although it depends on the document size and future growth of course.

Comment: We ended up changing the filter from a multikey index to a mixture of regular and compound indexes. We modified the queries accordingly and now, thanks to the index intersection feature, the queries run fast and smooth :-)